# How can I diff two git branches in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, bitbucket

### Background

I want to make sure that all commit messages on the pushed branch have a time log in it

ie. `add readme /spend 5m`

### Problem

I want to get the commit diff between two git branches in bitbucket pipeline,

this is my yaml pipeline config:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git log $BITBUCKET_BRANCH --oneline --not master
```

$BITBUCKET_BRANCH is the branch the pipeline is acting on.

but the pipeline is returning an error when trying to compare with master

```
+ git log $BITBUCKET_BRANCH --oneline --not master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Note that the setup step in the pipeline(this is pre-defined by bitbucket and I can't change it)

```
git clone --branch="abdullah-s/bitbucketpipelinesyml-created-online-wit-1489917130851" --depth 50 https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/abdullah-s/webook.git $BUILD_DIR;
git reset --hard ac61f080a28428bdd885735374164577a2b0aa43;
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:abdullah-s/webook.git
```

in the first command of the setup, bitbucket is cloning only one branch from my repo

## What I tried

I tried to pull master

```
- git checkout -b master
- git pull origin master
- git log $BITBUCKET_BRANCH --oneline --not master
```

but got an error

```
+ git pull origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

## Question

#### How can I compare two branches in bitbucket pipeline?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you rightfully point out, Bitbucket pipelines will only clone the specific branch that triggered the build.

As such, the [RefSpec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) will be set to the specific branch, and you'll be unable to merge or diff other branches.

For example, if the build was triggered on the develop branch, then the following refspec will be set:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

If you look at the available branches you'll see this :

```
+ git branch -a
* develop
  remotes/origin/develop
```

You can execute the following command :

```
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

to pull in all other branches / tags

```
From bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxxx
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      release    -> origin/release
 * [new tag]         xxxx -> xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm!
I also added these two commands to my **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file:

`- git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
 - git diff --name-status origin/master origin/development`

Supposing that the additional branch to compare was "development"

Comment: I still get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` when I do a `git diff master ./someFile.txt`

Comment: This answer has saved me from a pit of despair - thanks!

Comment: Should be marked as correct answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete answer for your question but just an hint : you can bypass the permission problem by storing your password as SECRET environnement variable and then identify the pipeline as yourself when you pull.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html

Comment: I'll try it when I get back to it and get back to you, thanks