# fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git

I used `git diff origin` often in the past.

In a different environment it does not work. I have no clue why.

```
user@host> git diff origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path 
       not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Status:

```
user@host> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Remotes:

```
user@host> git remote -v
origin  https://example.com/repos/djangotools (fetch)
origin  https://example.com/repos/djangotools (push)
```

Version:

```
user@host> git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

With "git version 1.8.1.4" `git diff origin` works.

BTW **I see the same err msg if I use "git diff origin/master"**

BTW2, I think the "/master" is redundant. The sane default is to compare the local branch with the same branch on the remote site.

Comment: A remote like `origin` alone is never expected in any `git diff` command.

Comment: @ElpieKay it works, I tested it with `git version 1.8.1.4`

Comment: I tried. Yes it works. It seems `git diff origin` is short for `git diff master origin/master` if the current branch is `master`. If the current branch has no remote tracking branch, it should not work.

Comment: As shown in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html the bare name `origin` will typically resolve via step 6, i.e., by resolving `origin/HEAD`. (If some earlier step resolves it first, though, you will get the earlier step's resolution. If `origin/HEAD` does not exist or is invalid, you will get the `fatal` you are seeing.) This pays no attention to the current branch's upstream setting: if you want to diff against that, use `@{u}`. You might say that Git uses the insane default. :-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `git diff` command typically expects one or more commit hashes to generate your diff. You seem to be supplying the name of a remote.

If you had a branch named `origin`, the commit hash at tip of the branch would have been used if you supplied `origin` to the diff command, but currently (with no corresponding branch) the command will produce the error you're seeing. It may be the case that you were previously working with a branch named `origin`.

An alternative, if you're trying to view the difference between your local branch, and a branch on a remote would be something along the lines of:

`git diff origin/<branchname>`

`git diff <branchname> origin/<branchname>`

[Or other documented variants](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

**Edit:** Having read further, I realise I'm slightly wrong, `git diff origin` is shorthand for diffing against the head of the specified remote, so `git diff origin` = `git diff origin/HEAD` ([compare local git branch with remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch), [Why is "origin/HEAD" shown when running "git branch -r"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354312/why-is-origin-head-shown-when-running-git-branch-r))

It sounds like your origin does not have a HEAD, in my case this is because my remote is a bare repository that has never had a HEAD set.

Running `git branch -r` will show you if `origin/HEAD` is set, and if so, which branch it points at (e.g. `origin/HEAD -> origin/<branchname>`).

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, `git branch -r` is empty in one repo and in the other it is not empty. That's why `git diff origin` works in one repo and not in the other.

Comment: `<branchname>` here is substituted for your specific named branch.

Answer (score 28):

I ran into the same situation where commands such as `git diff origin` or `git diff origin master` produced the error reported in the question, namely `Fatal: ambiguous argument...`

To resolve the situation, I ran the command

`git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master`

to set refs/remotes/origin/HEAD to point to the origin/master branch.

Before running this command, the output of `git branch -a` was:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

After running the command, the error no longer happened and the output of `git branch -a` was:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

(Other answers have already identified that the source of the error is HEAD not being set for origin. But I thought it helpful to provide a command which may be used to fix the error in question, although it may be obvious to some users.)

---

Additional information:

For anybody inclined to experiment and go back and forth between setting and unsetting refs/remotes/origin/HEAD, here are some examples.

To unset:
`git remote set-head origin --delete`

To set:
(additional ways, besides the way shown at the start of this answer)
`git remote set-head origin master` to set origin/head explicitly
OR
`git remote set-head origin --auto` to query the remote and automatically set origin/HEAD to the remote's current branch.

References:

- This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746099)
- This [SO Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639383/how-to-add-missing-origin-head-in-git-repo#comment81907091_17639471) and its associated answer
- `git remote --help` see set-head description
- `git symbolic-ref --help`

Comment: There are many similar answers here, but for me only running

    git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"

solved the issue, because the original problem was in shallow clone of single branch

Following advise here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886031/how-can-i-diff-two-git-branches-in-bitbucket-pipeline

Answer (score 17):

For those experiencing this error on CI/CD, adding the line below worked for me on my GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow right after running `pip install pyflakes diff-cover`:

> `git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

This is a snippet of the solution from the diff-cover github repo:

> **Solution**: diff-cover matches source files in the coverage XML report
>   with source files in the git diff. For this reason, it's important
>   that the relative paths to the files match. If you are using
>   coverage.py to generate the coverage XML report, then make sure you
>   run diff-cover from the same working directory.

I got the solution on the links below. It is a documented `diff-cover` error.

https://diff-cover.readthedocs.io/en/latest//README.html
https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff_cover/blob/master/README.rst

Hope this helps :-).

Comment: Took me two hours of digging around to find this answer, which finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you are having this issue in GitHub action you need to add:

```
fetch-depth: 0
```

So the step is

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
```

For additional info please check https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/296

Comment: Had similar case in Jenkins and this helped me figure out the issue. Thank you.

Comment: This helped me with a problem in GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes things might be simpler. I came here with the exact issue and tried all the suggestions. But later found that the problem was just the local file path was different and I was on a  different folder. :-)

eg -

~/myproject/mygitrepo/app/$  git diff app/TestFile.txt

should have been

~/myproject/mygitrepo/app/$  git diff TestFile.txt

Answer (score 4):

If `origin` points to a bare repository on disk, this error can happen if that directory has been moved (even if you update the working copy's remotes). For example

```
$ mv /path/to/origin /somewhere/else
$ git remote set-url origin /somewhere/else
$ git diff origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Pulling once from the new `origin` solves the problem:

```
$ git stash
$ git pull origin master
$ git stash pop
```

Answer (score 3):

- Remove opt/homebrew folder
  `cd /opt`,
  `sudo rm -rf homebrew`
- Install Homebrew :
  `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

If you are installing homebrew first time and facing this error than also on second attempt first clear remove the `/opt/homebrew` folder first.

Comment: This question of me is not related to Homebrew. It happend on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following setup then you will be ready to use brew

Run unintsall script :- `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

Set Git Compression :- `git config --global core.compression 0`

Set Git buffer size :- `git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

Run installation script :- `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get by without running the `Set Git Compression` and `Set Git buffer size` instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It might happen if you fetched/cloned with `depth=1`. So, you might also need to fetch the target branch from remote:

```
git remote set-branches origin 'your_target_branch'
git fetch --depth=1
// show local branches to confirm
git branch -a
// git diff ....
```

(note, replace `your_target_branch` with whatever you need, you might even need `master`)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on win
replace REL_PATH_TO_FILE with the relative path to the file to remove
[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)
The docs say full path - but that errored for me -so I tried rel path and it worked.

```
<from the repo dir>git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch REL_PATH_TO_FILE" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

start with **git fetch**

and **git diff master origin/master**

that is all.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a duplicate answer. Before posting, make sure someone else hasn't already posted the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this error when I was trying to update my branch by mistake.

I found that my branch was merged.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with the Bitbucket pipeline. Basically I needed to store the branch from remote repository locally before performing any further `git` operation on it.

Th wrong solution

```
git fetch origin develop
git log develop..$BITBUCKET_BRANCH // I was getting the error here
```

The right solution

```
git fetch origin develop:develop
git log develop..$BITBUCKET_BRANCH
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to unintall with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

And then, install with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```