# Why after git diff, there have such error?

Tags: git

```
$ git diff feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa develop
```

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'develop': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

the first branch is my local branch which contains my code changes;
the second branch is a remote branch which will be deployed into UAT daily;

What I want is to get the diff between my local branch and develop branch and patch the file into UAT automatically.

I can get the diff from Stash portal when create one pull request, but I want to get it from command line so that I could write some scripts to get the diff files and patch them into UAT by one click.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff

Comment: See https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1092

Comment: You have a file or directory called develop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096755/fatal-ambiguous-argument-origin-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `develop` you want to refer to is the name of a local branch, you can use this command to get rid of the ambiguity :

`git diff feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa refs/heads/develop`.

Comment: thx~, only local branch could be diff? can we diff one local branch with one remote branch? what I need is compare my local code with current development branch and get what I have change in my local branch, then I can get the changes to patch into our UAT, I can get it from stash, but I want to get it from command line so I can make some code to patch my change into UAT automatically.

Comment: Yes you can diff a local branch with a remote branch: first update your local tracking branch `<origin>/<branch>` with `git fetch <origin> <branch>` then use the diff command to make a patch : `git diff <origin>/<branch>..<local_branch> > your.patch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa develop --
```

Comment: lz46054@GCOTDVMMW741182 MINGW64 ~/git/server (feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa)
$ git diff feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa develop --
fatal: bad revision 'develop'

Comment: the first branch was copied in local, the develop was not copied, can I diff my local branch with one remote branch?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
git fetch origin;

git diff --name-only origin/develop...feature/C161920-5075-xtp-implementation-of-new-fidessa;
```