# Inside jenkinsfile how to get GIT difference between master branch and feature branch

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get git difference between master and feature branch but getting the error "command not found"  using below mentioned command:

COMMIT_CHANGE_SET = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff --name-only origin/master...$current_branch').trim()

As, I am able to get last commit changes using the below-mentioned command.

COMMIT_CHANGE_SET = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD').trim()

Jenkins pipeline git syntax command to get a difference master and feature branch

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'`with `"` in code below:

```
COMMIT_CHANGE_SET = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git diff --name-only $current_branch origin/master").trim()
```

Problem is you have to use `"` to be able to pass parameter.

Comment: I tried command inside  " " , but  getting error: 



ERROR:
'
[Pipeline] sh

+ git diff --name-only origin/master...DRG-111

fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...DRG-111': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:

'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

[Pipeline] }

'

Comment: `COMMIT_CHANGE_SET = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git diff --name-only $current_branch origin/master").trim()
`

Comment: Updated code still getting the same error:
`+ git diff --name-only DRG-111 origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: @ShashiB check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096755/fatal-ambiguous-argument-origin-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the-working/45096973)

Comment: I tried  which are mentioned in the [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096755/fatal-ambiguous-argument-origin-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the-working/45096973)  

I am getting git difference using command on my local machin
`git diff origin/master`  and `git diff current_branch origin/master`
but same command is not working in Jenkinsfile and getting error: ** fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree **